# Accessing Array.items[] in a for-loop error

Tags: java, android, class, for-loop, libgdx

With the aim of getting a better performance I'm fine tuning the code, looking through the DDMS tracer. One aspect is `Array.get(x)` which is more expensive than `Array.items[x]`

We can directly access the `items` proving the array type is Object, or, we specify the array type in the constructor, like so:

```
Array<MyClass> foo = new Array<MyClass>(MyClass.class)
```

This works fine, however, how do I specify the last `MyClass.class` in a for loop? I have this at the moment:

```
for (Array<MyClass> listOfObjects : allObjects) {

    for (int i=0; i<listOfObjects.size; i++) {

        MyClass myObj = listOfObjects.get(i);   
        //MyClass myObj = listOfObjects.items[i];
```

The commented line works fine, but trying to get rid of the overhead, I want to supply the `(MyClass.class)' like mentioned above. Where can I do this in that for-loop constructor?

Many thanks
J

Comment: This is weird. In your enhanced for-loop foo is already the current item. In your snippet you are instead trying to access it with a non-existent variable `i`.

Comment: Oh, I've copied my code incorrectly. Updating..

Comment: To use the advanced for loop the way you've got it set up, the Array<MyClass> should be an Array<Array<MyClass>>

Comment: Won't help your current issue, but make sure you use `listOfObjects.size()`

Comment: `size()` doesn't exist, as this is a Libgdx Array object: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're trying to do is pointless. Please read this great article: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/

You are trying to generate some minimal optimization, while at the same time greatly reducing readibility and maintainability.

If you want less overhead, it would probably be wiser to look at a language like C++, rather than trying to hack basic java for loops.

Another thing you may want to look into is Java 8, which has added functionality for executing loops concurrently with Streams.

Comment: Interesting. The thing is, small changes like this are making a difference in our FPS, so it's the only route I know to go down at the moment...

Comment: I don't know anything about the gdx performance of their Array class, but have you considered using the Java HashSet, or the gdx equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

```
Array<MyClass> foo = new Array<MyClass>(MyClass.class)
```

Note that you are creating a NEW array with this line, passing it a class argument. From http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html

```
Array(java.lang.Class arrayType)
Creates an ordered array with items of the specified type and a capacity of 16.
```

I don't see you trying to create new Arrays in the other code you posted. Are you trying to populate each `listOfObjects` in `allObjects`?
If so, you would want to do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allObjects.size; i++)
{
    allObjects.items[i] = new Array<MyClass>(MyClass.class);
}
```

If you are simply trying to loop through these arrays, there is no class argument needed. I would suggest comparing the `Array` class to other Gdx or Java collections if the speed of iteration is too slow.

This quote from above link may also be notable if you do a lot of removing from the arrays.

`A resizable, ordered or unordered array of objects. If unordered, this class avoids a memory copy when removing elements (the last element is moved to the removed element's position).`